# Merging data in Open/LibreOffice Calc

Tags: csv, openoffice-calc

I have two sets of data in .csv format which share a field called `sku`. The second one has additional columns which need to be added to the first, but they have different sets of data, only some of which overlaps.

The only data that needs to be merged is for `sku`s that already appear in the first. For example:

File 1

```
sku,foo
a,hello
b,world
```

File 2

```
sku,bar
a,0
b,1
c,2
d,3
```

would result in:

```
sku,foo,bar
a,hello,0
b,world,1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OpenOffice:

1. Copy paste your two dataset into the same workbook in two different worksheet.
2. use the function vlookup (same as in Excel) to merge your two data set in the same worksheet. The syntax is =VLOOKUP( valueToSearchFor ; tableToSearchIn ; columnIdentifier ; isTableSorted? ) ([source](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=46746))
3. Then you can use the concatenate function CONCATENATE(text1; text2; ... text30) to merge your content into a single cell. ([source](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_CONCATENATE_function))

Comment: An example:  =VLOOKUP(A1,$Sheet2.$A$1:$B$500,2, 0).   VLOOKUP is sort of analogous to a JOIN statement in SQL.  Very handy.  Thanks!