# Copy/Move cells by id

Tags: excel, calc

How can I move values from Worksheet 1 column B to Worksheet 2 column B, based on a unique ID in column A? Some IDs are duplicates and some values are empty, I would like to ignore empty values.

---

**Worksheet 1:**

```
A      B
23452  value1
23452  
53252  value2
67452  value3
```

**Worksheet 2:**

```
A      B
53252
23452    
67452
```

**Wanted Result (Worksheet 2):**

```
A      B
53252  value2
23452  value1 
67452  value3
```

---

What I have tried

[Merging data in Open/Libreoffice calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709225/merging-data-in-open-libreoffice-calc) - could not figure this out for my specific requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple `INDEX-MATCH` formula,

[image]

In column B of sheet2,

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'.A:B;MATCH(A1;'Sheet1'.A:A;0);2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am getting an error in OpenOffice `Error: Pair missing` - [Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/6ef0151accf19008e4831984bf2f4c28.png)

Comment: @Tod Looks like the delimiter should be `;` instead of `,`. Please try the updated formula

Comment: This now returns `#NAME?` I tried the comma delimited formula in Excel and it worked, but on larger amounts of data it just returns 0 in the first cell and nothing more.

Comment: @Tod Please update the screenshots of the error that you get to the question. Let me take a look

Comment: Data: [Screenshot A](http://i.gyazo.com/587fcfc5de146afa95ba62096865b59e.png) Formula:
 [Screenshot B](http://i.gyazo.com/5f232c2898cd1b0ef156512a09fb16a1.png)

Comment: @Tod Try this updated formula. If this is not working, then you may have to spend some time googling to find the equivalent of index-match and how to refer another sheet within a formula